# ECLIPSE RCP app: view disappears after opening another window

Tags: view, treeview, eclipse-rcp, hyperlink, .refresh

I have 3 views in a window. The first view has content from a tree viewer. The second view has content in FillLayout. Both views get the data from the DB.
Once I click on a link from the second view, I get the new window popping out. But this window looses both first and second views. I don't know what I am missing here.
Any insight is highly appreciated.

Comment: What window are you opening? Could you paste some code snippet?

Comment: Here is the code snippet: button1 exists in window 1 : Buttton1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {    
   public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    try {

     PlatformUI.getWorkbench().openWorkbenchWindow(Perspective.ID,null);
     

      
    } catch (WorkbenchException e1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
    }
   }    
  });

Answer (score 0):

I think the window you are opening is showing just the views which are not opened in other windows, thats why you see just a single view. You should search for other ways of opening a new window (as far as I know there are many ways and openWorkbenchWindow is just one of them)
Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686265/eclipse-rcp-application-multi-window-design-for-multiple-monitors) for some help, looks quite similar to your problem.